# Get Markers on Cluster Click, get snippets and properties

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My application has a Google Map working fine clustering the markers.
I am displaying a AlertDialog with the markers that are inside the cluster item when the zoom is max.

```
mClusterManager
        .setOnClusterClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener<MyItem>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClusterClick(final Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {

               if(map.getCameraPosition().zoom>=21) {

        /*HERE I WANT TO GET ALL ITEMS ON MY CLUSTER AND GET

        THE LIST OF MY MARKERS. BUT THE PROBLEM IS: /*

/* I wanna iterate the cluster.getItems() and use something like
        cluster.getItems().get(i).getSnippet and store

      the markers snippets in a array. But it's not possible to get the
snippet from cluster.getItems /*                 


               } else {
                   map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                   cluster.getPosition(), (float) Math.floor(map
                                           .getCameraPosition().zoom + 2)), 300,
                           null);
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look the only way to do that is make a Hashmap(>Marker,somestring>) and then add every marker in it and then you can call Hashmap.getobject(somestring + i).showsnippet and do whatever you want.
I hope you get the somestring and i part.